# Could we rename "Close" to "Flag for Review"?

Tags: feature-request

So it seems people get annoyed when their question is "Closed".  The reasoning behind closing a question is generally to maintain a certain "answerability" requirement, without which the functioning of the StackExchange format seems to break down.

Is there any way to change what it's called to "Close" a question?  Straightforwardly, in closing a question as we currently do, we invite the questioner to review through comments and edits, to see if a more concise, answerable version of the question emerges through discussion and refinement.

A lot of grief and a disincentive to engage more constructively in this review process might be avoided by simply changing the "Closed" status to "Pending Review" with no substantial adjustment to the operation of the status flag in question.  So, could this terminology be changed?

Comment: 'Pending review' would give the OP the opportunity to review and revise the question to meet an answerability requirement.  What I think would need to accompany the 'Pending review' flag is an indication, which may not be apparent esp. to a new user, of what the problem is - lack of clarity, insufficient detail, missing context, &c. At present the relevant problem - the reason for closure - is displayed only when the question has been closed. I seldom close a question at once, even if I think it is definitely faulty (unless it is racist, &c.), but to leave a comment indicating its faultiness.